# UnboundLocalError local variables referenced before assignment / Consideration

Tags: python, django, variables, scope

I have the following function based view

```
def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            results = SearchQuerySet().models(Post).filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()
            # count total results
            total_results = results.count()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/search.html', {'form': form,
                                                     'cd': cd,
                                                     'results': results,
                                                     'total_results': total_results})
```

When I execute my url that call this function I get the following error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cd' referenced before assignment
     [25/Aug/2016 22:48:13] "GET /blog/search/ HTTP/1.1" 500 69440
```

`cd`, `results` and `total_results` variables are declared and used in a scope different to the `return render(request ...)` sentence at the end.

It's for this reason the error.

I've initialized this variables as a globals of this way:

```
cd = results=total_results=None
```

before of the conditional sentences

```
def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()

    # Initialize variables
    cd = results=total_results=None
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            results = SearchQuerySet().models(Post).filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()
            # count total results
            total_results = results.count()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/search.html', {'form': form,
                                                     'cd': cd,
                                                     'results': results,
                                                     'total_results': total_results})
```

And my GET request it's works

```
[25/Aug/2016 23:05:33] "GET /blog/search/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2260
```

I could solve this of some another way?
This functionality is for search in a web, 
Is this good when I have many users using this functionality?

I think that the solution is not good practice ... I don't know.

Comment: You should not update your question when one issue is resolved. Because people who have answered the question will not get idea that question is updated. Instead post another question

Comment: I believe your original issue is resolved and you are facing new one.

Comment: Hi @MoinuddinQuadri I type my question the first time already having clear the solution. I just update my question when I ask if the solution of initialized variables was suited. The response that you refer me of a kindly way it's the origin of my question in my post question.

Answer (score 1):

It means, either your `form.is_valid()` is `False` or, you are not making the `GET` request.

Add `cd = results = total_results = None` before the first if condition. Because, in your current code, if any of the `if` condition fails, `cd`, `results` and `total_results` will not be initialized and hence will throw this error. Your updated code should be:

```
def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    cd = results = total_results = None  # <--- Add this to your code
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        . . . Something Something
    return render(request, 'blog/post/search.html', {'form': form,
                                                     'cd': cd,
                                                     'results': results,
                                                     'total_results': total_results})
```

Comment: Initialize the variables, obviously is a solution, Is this a good practice or regardless my question does not have sense?

Comment: It is not a good practice. You need to handle it in much better way. Because, if any of the condition is not satisfied, that means it is an invalid request. You should return proper response message. For example, your code just supports `GET` call. If method is not `GET` return 'Unsupported request type error'.Else if form is not valid , ask user to enter valid form. In both the cases return `400` status code i.e bad request

Comment: I understand that you tell me. I would like to ask you if is possible that you orient me a few more about of another approach in relation to your recommendations. Is possible that you can help me to make a response message taking in account the `POST` and `GET` calls for manage the possible scenarios or exceptions? Excuse me my boldness with this petition

Answer (score 1):

```
def post_search(request):
#cd = results = total_results = None
form = SearchForm()
if 'query' in request.GET:
    form = SearchForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        results = SearchQuerySet().models(Post).filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()
        total_results = results.count()
    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/search.html',
                  {'form': form,
                   'cd': cd,
                   'results': results,
                   'total_results': total_results})
return render(request,'blog/post/search.html', {'form': form})
```

this work fine.
Enjoy